# ionic back button not working inside the tabbed view

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have 3 views named **view1, view2 and view3**.

I have a back button in three views and i am having **'tabbed view'** in **view3**

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar bar-subheader">
        <ion-nav-bar>
            <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear">
                <a class="button icon-left ion-chevron-left button-clear button-dark"></a>
            </ion-nav-back-button>                           
        </ion-nav-bar> 
    </ion-header-bar>
```

And i am able to going back from **view2** to **view1** but not from **view3** to **view2** (i.e, **view3 containing tabs**).

[image]

Comment: could you put this in a plunker ?